# Building ruby version 3.2 with openssl version 3.0 gives error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘X509_CRL'

Tags: ruby, openssl

Ruby version 3.2 : https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/1c7624469880bcb964be09a49e4907873f45b026

openssl v3 is installed under /usr/local_ssl_3.0.0.

./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local_ssl_3.0.0

I get the following error when running make:

```
openssl_missing.c:24:13: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘X509_CRL {aka const struct X509_crl_st}’
  *psig = crl->signature;
             ^~
openssl_missing.c: In function ‘ossl_X509_REQ_get0_signature’:
openssl_missing.c:36:13: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘X509_REQ {aka const struct X509_req_st}’
  *psig = req->signature;
             ^~
```

Comment: Ruby still depends on OpenSSL 1.1.

Comment: Is there a way to compile it with both the versions if it still depends on 1.1? I have 1.1 on the sytem but need to build ruby 3.2 that can install on systems running openssl v3 only.

Comment: When I check rbenv, I get `/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/openssl/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.12 24 Oct 2023)` . Did ruby 3.2.2 switch to OpenSSL 3 ?  I am getting similar compiler errors here: `openssl_missing.h:230:41: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘EVP_MD_CTX’ .`  3.0.12 is a version I installed manually... I'll try removing it to go back to Ubuntu 20.04 default (1.1.1)